# What is this called?

Tags: identification

I need to buy some more of these online but I'm not sure what they're called.

Does someone know what this is?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks like Laurus nobilis, or Bay laurel, except the leaves are a bit yellow. That could be down to nutrient or light shortage, or possibly insufficient root room, but you don't mention any scent - the leaves are used in cooking, so there should be a distinctive scent, especially if bruised. Pic below, but if there's no scent, this ID is incorrect, and it may be an Elaeagnus variety instead

https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Laurus_nobilis_002.JPG

Comment: Definitely either nitrogen deficiency or possibly iron.  What have you been using for additions of chemicals to your potting soil?  Is this potting soil or garden soil?  How often. The scent should define this guy...what kind of flower do you remember?

Comment: It might also be Laurus nobilis 'Aurea', the yellow-leaved bay tree.

Comment: @Brenn well that would certainly explain why its yellow!